# Como converter pattern do regex do C# para C++?

Tags: c++

Eu estou tentando usar o regex do C++ mas estou tendo algumas dificuldades, uma delas é que o pattern estava em um código C#, e eu não sei praticamente nada de regex em C++, e por isso o código não funciona como deveria em C++

Aqui vai o trecho do código que não funciona como deveria:

```
if (!std::regex_match("BLUS31029", std::regex("^B[LC][JUEAK][SM]\d{5}$")))
    print_error("Invalid game id: " + game_id);
else
    ::id_ = game_id;
}
```

PS: Eu já troquei o `regex_match` por `regex_search` e mesmo assim não funcionou

Comment: "não funciona" significa que aparece algum erro ao compilar o programa, ou o resultado não é o esperado? Qual compilador você está utilizando?

Comment: @Gomiero Não funciona no sentido de dar o resultado esperado q no caso é true, e estou usando o Visual Studio 2019

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na *string* da expressão regular, o caractér `\d` é reconhecido pelo compilador
de forma **incorreta** como um *escape sequence* ([sequência de escape](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/cpp/c-language/escape-sequences?view=msvc-160)).

Em várias linguagens, a barra invertida `\` seguida de um
símbolo, é utilizada para representar caractéres que não
podem ser impressos ou que possuem significados especiais.

Exemplo: `\n` representa a ação "Nova Linha".

Para representar o caractér barra invertida, é necessário utilizar
duas barras `\\`, para indicar ao compilador que não se trata de uma
sequencia de escape.

Dependendo da configuração do Visual Studio (2019), durante a compilação,
ele deve ter emitido um aviso informando uma sequencia não
reconhecida:

> warning C4129: 'd': unrecognized character escape sequence

O trecho do programa na pergunta, com a expressão regular corrigida, fica da seguinte forma:

```
if (!std::regex_match("BLUS31029", std::regex("^B[LC][JUEAK][SM]\\d{5}$")))
    print_error("Invalid game id: " + game_id);
else
    ::id_ = game_id;
}
```

Comment: O problema está na string em si, não no pattern, eu descobri isso dps, a string que eu coloco no regex tem algo errado que faz com o que o resultado do match dê false, com o pattern tá tudo certo